# Rails - Where should this code go to stay true to MVC design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails, and working my way through a couple of books, coding small test projects as I go. My latest dev app is a question and answer program. The idea is to have a database table full of questions. A user will bring up the web app and be presented with the first question. User enters answer into a form, and if it is correct, he gets the next question. Pretty simple.

So, I've used generate scaffold to create a questions table and a users table. This works well - I can navigate to the system-generated views to add/edit/delete questions and users.

I then created a new controller called gateway. I made this my root controller and gave it an index method. The index method takes in a user ID as a URL parameter and fetches the appropriate question for the user. It then loads a view which displays the question and has a form where the user enters the answer.

I'm now programming the logic to test the answer - I was doing this in a new method called "test_answer" in the gateway controller, but I feel like I'm now breaking MVC design, since this code is not directly related to displaying a view. I'm a bit confused as to where I should put code like this (the method tests the answer, if correct increments the user's level, if wrong redirects to an error page)

Should it go in an existing model (user or question)? Should it stay in the gateway controller? Should I create a new file in /lib?

I get the general concept of MVC (views display info, models store and manipulate data, controllers handle interactions between the two) but I'm not sure how this code fits in.

Thanks!

For reference, here is my current gateway.rb controller - please, pick it apart! I'm sure there are a number of questionable bits in there...

```
class GatewayController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:uid]
      @user = User.where(:uid => params[:uid]).first
    else
      @user = User.where(:uid => "000").first
    end  
    @question = Question.where(:question_number => @user.current_level).first
    session[:uid] = @user.uid
    session[:answer] = @question.answer_text
  end

# POST /gateway/answer
# POST /gateway/answer.xml
  def answer
    #below is code I feel shouldn't be here...the logic to test the answer and then increment user's level
    if (params[:user_answer]) == session[:answer]
      @user = User.where(:uid => session[:uid]).first
      @user.increment!(:current_level)
      respond_to do |format|
        #code here will redirect to "Correct answer" page
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|    
        #code here will redirect to "Wrong answer" page
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put that test_answer in your model because it is concerning the data. This will return a boolean value in which the controller will then compare on, to determine whether or not to redirect to an error page.

**Semi Pseudo Code:**

```
class Question
  def test_answer(arg)
    if answer_is_right
      user.incr_level
    else
      false
    end
  end
end

class GatewayController < ApplicationController
  #code

  def answer
    if !question.test_answer(param)
      redirect_to error_page_path
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Which model? I have one for users and one for questions. The test_answer concerns testing vs the question data, but changing (incrementing) the user data. Curious to hear your thoughts, thanks!

Comment: I'd put it in your question model, and you can access the user by calling the belongs_to relation(assuming you have a belong_to).

Comment: @user I would put it on both, the user model could have something like `answer_question(question, answer)` and the question model might have 'answer(answer)`

Comment: @mike - there is no belongs_to relationship - I didn't think that would be appropriate, since there is no real relationship between the questions and users -- except that users are "authorized" to answer a certain level of questions through a user.current_level integer. It doesn't seem the users own the questions, nor do the questions own the users, so would a relationship be correct in this case?

Comment: In that case, you are correct, there would not be a relationship if a user does not own a question. Because of this, I would still put the test_answer method in your question model. However I would pass the current_user into that method to incr the id if necessary.

Comment: @vadim - not sure what you accomplish by placing it in both? I'm just looking to place the function that will check the answer (supplied to the controller by the user via form). Do I have a basic misunderstanding of how this is supposed to work?

Comment: @mike - the way I was accessing the user from various places was to store the current user's UID in the session...is there a better way to access the user (to increment the level) from the question model? Or better to just have the question model pass back the result of test_answer to the controller and have the controller pass that to an increment method in the user model?

Comment: @user you accomplish [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The user class only cares about whether or not the answer was correct, not how to verify that it is correct. While the question class only cares about how to mark an answer as correct or not, not with what should happen to the user.

Comment: @vadim - ahh, gotcha - think I misunderstood your initial response. So flow would be: gateway controller displays question, user answers it, controller calls question model's answer method and is returned true/false, controller then calls user model's increment method (if result was true) or returns error page (if result was false) - is that conceptually correct?

Comment: @user, that's one way of doing it. The way I thought of was for the controller to call the user's answer_question method, which in turn would call the question's answer method. It makes the controller a little cleaner and also encapsulates logic around users question answering (what happens if the answer is correct vs wrong) to the user class.