# Trouble with Rails MVC concepts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns

Ugh - not sure why I'm having so much trouble with this.

Writing a simple question and answer app (see [Rails - Where should this code go to stay true to MVC design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556388/rails-where-should-this-code-go-to-stay-true-to-mvc-design) for some details)

Trying to stick to MVC principles and proper design - this app is simply a learning experience, so I want to make sure I'm doing things in a generally accepted way

The referenced question gave me advice to split up my functionality into the different models. However, trying to implement this, I find myself passing parameters all over the place and I just get a feeling that I'm not doing something right. So, here's the basic layout of the app and the tasks I am trying to accomplish - if someone could let me know if I'm on the right track...

Question Model: contains id(pkey), question_number(int), question_text(string), answer_text(string)

User Model: contains: id(pkey), uid(string), current_question(int), name(string)

I created both of the above with scaffold so they have all the default routes, controller actions, etc...

I created a gateway controller and set it to be my default page through routes.rb

The idea is, user browses to localhost:3000/?uid="whatever" and the index page displays the current question (Question.find_by_question_number(@user.current_question))

User enters answer in a form, which POSTs it to an action. In my first draft, this called an action in the gateway controller which checked if the answer was correct.

Now, I am trying to take vadim's advice in my last question and keep the user login in user and the question logic in question. So now my form POSTs to the users controller.

Here's where I get mixed up. The logic code shouldn't be in the controller, right? So I call a method in the model, passing it stuff like the user's answer and the question id since I can't read the session in the model. This works fine, I can now take care of the logic in the user model - so now the user model calls a method in the question model to actually check the answer. That means I have to instantiate my question object using the ID I passed, then call another method, passing (again!) the answer. Etc...etc...

See what I mean? I definitely understand the value of MVC in theory, but whenever I try and implement it I wind up with a mess like this. It this correct, and it just seems like overcomplicating things because my program is so simple?

Can someone walk me through how you would split the logic up? You don't need to post actual code, just what you would put where, like:

Gateway Controller:
-display question to user
-take answer and pass to XXX controller

XXX controller:
-call method Foo in XXX model, passing X and Y

The basic flow should be, user is shown a question, user answers question, answer is compared to the correct answer in the question model, message is returned based on result, and it answer was correct, user's current_question is incremented.

Thanks so much for the help, I have books and Google and have been reading my a$$ off, just lost in the sauce here. This is my first attempt to venture outside the safety of pre-written example code, so please be gentle!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic flow should be:

- a method in the controller selects the question and displays a view with a form in it
- the users submits this form
- this is a POST to the controller
- in the controller you check the result and display it to the user in another/the same view.

Now to the model. You can put methods in there that check certain things. Still, the controller handles the work, it calls the method and processes the results in the controller.

Comment: That is sort of how I originally structured it...so, I could have the gateway controller get the POST, call a method to test the answer (maybe in the Question model, passing it the question ID and user answer), have that return Bool, and controller acts on that...for example, calling a method in User model to increment the current_level, then displaying the proper view... does that sound right? I was confused by Vadim's comment @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556388/rails-where-should-this-code-go-to-stay-true-to-mvc-design where he rec'd calling the question method from the user method

Comment: Sounds perfectly right to me. And I don't really understand Vadim's comment in the other thread.

Comment: well, i think that sorts it out. makes much more sense in my mind, anyway - thanks for 'talking it out' with me :)

Comment: You are welcome! I still remember my start with Rails, it's complicated :)   (If you are interested follow the link in my profile, there are several articles on Rails you might find useful for learning Rails)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases in a Q&A app, you would have a Question Model, an Answer Model, and a User model. Your actions are:

1. displaying answers (the show method for the Questions controller)
2. Showing the new answer form
3. Posting to the create method on the Answers controller.

Some code:

```
class Question
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :users
  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_presence_of :question
  validates_uniqueness_of :question_id, :scope => :user_id
end

class User
  has_many :answers
end
```

Routes

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers
end
```

answers_controller

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @answer = Answer.new(params[:answer])
    @answer.user = current_user
    @answer.question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    if @answer.save
      flash[:success] = "Saved!"
      redirect_top @answer.question
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Jesse - I think when I said "Q&A" you thought it was like SO, where someone asks a question and multiple answers are posted. Your code looks great for that scenario - but my program is more like a trivia thing, where there is a database table of questions with proper answers, and the user is being asked to provide the correct answer to question X. So in that case, there is no real relationship between the users and the questions, and no reason to separate the questions and answers...right? :)

Comment: I would still structure the code the same as above. I would think about having a "possible_answers" table under the question that would be a list of possible answers for the question, and then has_one :correct_answer on the question.

Comment: Jesse - but why do you care about the possible answers? If the answer is correct the user moves to the next level, but if they are wrong, you just display a particular view and then repeat the question. Why do you want to record or manipulate the wrong answers in a DB table? Not trying to say you're wrong, genuinely curious as that never even crossed my mind - thanks!

Comment: In trivia, There's a question and 4 possible answers. The user picks A,B,C,or D right? That's how I structured it. I would not care about incorrect answers.

Comment: lol - you're right, again, really bad communication skills on my part. My app has a 1:1 question:answer ratio. However, since the whole goal here is to learn Ruby/Rails, I think I'm going to change this to a "classic" trivia model and structure it like you specified. Thanks for the inspiration!!